# Vector analysis questions

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

I need some help with the following questions, I have made an attempt at both which is below but don't think its right. Any help in where I'm going wrong would be appreciated.

[image]

1)

$$\int_{0}^{2} (3ui+u^2j+(u+2)k   *  (2ui-3uj+(u-2)k) dx$$

$ $
 \begin{array}{ccc}
i & j & k \\
u & u^2 & (u+2) \\
2u & -3u & (u-2) \end{array}

$i(u^2(u-2)-(-3u(u+2)))-j((u^2-2u)-(2u^2+4u))+k((-3u^2)-(2u^3))$
$= -3u^3-u^2+2u$

$$\int_{0}^{2} (3u^3-u^2+2u) dx$$

$$ \frac{-3u^4}{4}-\frac{u^3}{3}+\frac{2u^2}{2}$$

$$ \frac{-3*2^4}{4}-\frac{2^3}{3}+{2^2}=-12-\frac{8}{3}+4=\frac{-32}{3}$$

2)

fo this question i can do a similar question where $s=(t,t^2,t^3)$ but am having trouble with this one. First i tried to just get the values of $x,y,z$ and input them into A. and then continue on as normal. This gave me an answer but it doesn't seem right at all.

Answer (score 0):

The result of the cross product between $\bf{F}$ and $\bf{V}$ is a vector and not a scalar. You have to integrate the components in $i$, $j$, $k$, separately. In addition please replace $K$ by $k$.
As the surface integral you can have a look here http://mathinsight.org/surface_integral_vector_field_introduction .

Comment: thanks for the response and the site. Im not exactly sure what you mean when you say $(i,j,k)$ have to be integrated separately. As in they have to be integrate in an earlier step ?

Comment: $$ \mathbf{r}(t) = \langle x(t), y(t), z(t) \rangle \implies \int \mathbf{r}(t) \text{ d}t = \left( \int x(t) \text{ d}t \right) \mathbf{i} + \left( \int y(t) \text{ d}t \right) \mathbf{j} + \left( \int z(t) \text{ d}t \right) \mathbf{k} $$

Comment: is this what you mean.

$\int_ (u^3-8u+3u^2)i-\int_(u^2+2u-2u^3)j+\int_(-3u^2-2u^3)k$

$(\frac{u^4}{4}-4u^2+u^3)i-(\frac{u^3}{3}+u^2-\frac{u^4}{2})j+(-u^3-\frac{u^4}{2})k$

After this i just added like terms and substituted u for 2 and was able to get an answer but isnt that nice. Is that the right procedure or are you meant to integrate again

Comment: The procedure is correct. Since a cross product between vector is a vector you have to integrate the three vector components.In addition the integral must be evaluated between 0 and 2. Then:

$ \int_{0}^{2}(\frac{u^4}{4}-4u^2+u^3)i- \int_{0}^{2}(\frac{u^3}{3}+u^2-\frac{u^4}{2})j+ \int_{0}^{2}(-u^3-\frac{u^4}{2‌​})k = -4 i +\frac{4}{3} j+ 0 k$